# Magento 2: Shopping Cart Rule discount based on item quantity

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, magento2.3.2

I'm a Magento 2 newbie. My customer wants to add a cart rule like,
apply 2% discount if item quantity >=12
apply 4% discount if item quantity >=24
apply 6% discount if item quantity >=36
apply 8% discount if item quantity >=48
and so on.

I've added a rule like below image. But here the discount will remain at 2% even if 24 is ordered. 
What changes need to done to follow above conditions. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I have checked with same values provided in screenshot and it is working fine for single product added in cart with 48 quantity.

Comment: For every 12 quantity the discount gets incremented by 2%... For 12 qty - 2%, 24 qty -4%